# C# - Entity Framework Query returns NullExpression when not supposed to

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

First of all this is my first question and I am a junior so please bare with me if I say anything stupid.

I'm encountering a strange issue in my C# code which behaves like this:

I have a simple database query inside a foreach statement which returns NullExpression though there is always something to return (I will have to ask you to believe me here).

What is peculiar about this is that if I add a breakpoint at the line of the query and go step by step, the query returns the values. It is like when running normally, there is not enough time for the query to return the values from the database (even with the 'await' keyword).

The query:

```
var optModelProperty = await _modelProperty.GetWhere(x =>
                                        x.Name == property.Parent && x.OptModelId == id &&
                                        x.ElementId == modelElement.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
parentId = optModelProperty.Id;
```

**Works:**
Adding a breakpoint at the line of the query - the query works fine if executing those two lines step by step (No more NullException)

**No luck:**
I tried to add a thread.sleep of up to 1000 ms between the query and the next line - still nullException.
I tried rebuilding and cleaning the solution - nothing.
I cleared the Nuget cache - same as above.
I restarted Docker - no change.
I restarted Visual Studio - no change.
I tried to remove the 'await' and 'Async' keywords - no change.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem *might* be that Entity Framework uses lazy loading, that is it doesn't even start to get data, before You actually uses the result.
Try appending a `ToList()`:

```
var optModelProperty = await _modelProperty.GetWhere(x =>
           x.Name == property.Parent && x.OptModelId == id &&                                        
           x.ElementId == modelElement.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ToList();
```

This will force EF to execute the query.

Comment: I'm actually retrieving an object, but I managed to test with `.ToString()` (I guess it should be the same thing).
Same behaviour, if running normally -> nullException. Running with brakepoints, the object is retrieved and converted to string.